# Copy subitem from listview to clipboard

Tags: c#, listview, copy

I have a program that allows a user to upload information to a database for code debugging. The initial code is uploaded, then displayed in a list view. I am trying to figure out a way to copy a single cell of data, specifically the "Code" cell, so when a user clicks on the cell they can copy just that code, not the whole row.

**I have tried using labeledit, but this allows editing on the whole form which isn't the functionality im looking for. I want locked cells for everything but the code cells, but then only allowing Copying from that cell.**

Here is how my list view is prepared.

**InitializeListView**

```
 private void InitializeListView()
        {
            // Set the view to show details.
            lbxBugged.View = View.Details;


            // Allow the user to rearrange columns.
            lbxBugged.AllowColumnReorder = true;

            // Select the item and subitems when selection is made.
            lbxBugged.FullRowSelect = true;

            // Display grid lines.
            lbxBugged.GridLines = true;

            // Sort the items in the list in ascending order.
            lbxBugged.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

            // Attach Subitems to the ListView
            lbxBugged.Columns.Add("ID", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Code", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Description", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            lbxBugged.Columns.Add("Author", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        }
```

**PopulateListView**

```
public void populateListView()
{
    lbxBugged.Items.Clear();
    SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Bug_ID, Bug_Code, Bug_Description, Bug_Author FROM tblBugs ORDER BY Bug_ID ASC", mySqlConnection);

    try
    {
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["Bug_ID"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Code"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Description"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(dr["Bug_Author"].ToString());

            lbxBugged.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }


}
```